# How can I fix ios transition for width, height and transform?

Tags: ios, css, transform, transition

On ios (safari and chrome), if I change an element size(width, height) and also I rotate it, transitioning all these properties doesn't work as expected.

I've tried using scale and it solves the problem, but using scale affects the size of the children, so it's not an optimal solution.

```
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-13deg) scale(1);
transform-origin: center;
transition: all .3s ease-out;
```

This is the wrong behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXTG3.jpg
Here I have a pen with the code: https://codepen.io/alexcondur/pen/pBjOWM?editors=0100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after wrapping my head for 2 days around this I found the solution. 
The idea is to center the element without using `translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);`
 and only keeping the `rotate` transform.
So, I'm using flex(I think grid will do too)

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  transform: rotate(14deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/alexcondur/pen/ROaVMe 
 If the parent of the element would be smaller than the children, I would use margin to position my child to center. For example:

```
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: -175px 0 0 -100px;
  transform: rotate(14deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this maybe:

```
transform-origin: center center;  /* center twice */
transform-box: fill-box;
```